# MS Flow send an email, add addresses from SharePoint list

Tags: json, email, office365, power-automate, mailing-list

Here is what I have thus far:

1. Set a schedule to run
2. Connect to the SharePoint list
3. Select from that list
4. Join the email addresses separated by a ;
5. Send an email to those addresses

[image: each action details]
[image: last]
[image: error i'm getting]

I probably need to parse or extract the email addresses from that output before the join right? I need to figure out what action to use to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use select, you're creating an object array.  You can use the compose feature inside a Apply to Each loop to do what you're trying to do. When you use a compose inside an Apply to Each control, you're essentially creating an array.

After the Apply to Each, create a Compose action that joins the output of Compose with a semicolon

```
join(outputs('Compose'),';')
```

[image]

Comment: That did the trick Thanks! I used the title field for the email addresses.